# SQL query to retrieve 20 columns along with there values from the given table

Tags: sql-server

**EDIT-1**

I need a SQL query which enables me to retrieve first 20 columns from a table along with there values and another SQL query which enables me to retrieve from 20th column to 60th column from the same table along with values.

Comment: Did you tried anything ? If you don't know what to use then HINT - `Dynamic sql , INFORMATION_SCHEMA`

Comment: Google is your friend...  This almost reads like you are looking for the first 20 rows and not first 20 columns?

Comment: SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INDUS2_MPS.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'main_mps_dqs_analog' And COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%st2%'...This I know.,but how to retrieve first 20 column is tricky..

Comment: Really?  you can't just do a: SELECT TOP 20 COLUMN_NAME....

Comment: How to retrieve values between 20th column to 60th column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @params NVARCHAR(MAX) = '@columns NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT'

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT @columns = STUFF(
(
    SELECT '',''+ [column_name] FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE (table_schema = ''dbo''
          AND table_name = ''TableName'')
          AND (ordinal_position <= 20 OR (ordinal_position >=20  AND ordinal_position <=60)) FOR XML PATH('''')),1,1,'''')'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params, @columns OUTPUT

SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + @columns + ' FROM dbo.TableName'

EXEC(@sql)
```

Notice that you should take care of possible `SQL Injection`, if you will pass TableName or Schema with parameters to this statement.

EDIT:

Try this for filtering:

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + @columns + ' FROM dbo.TableName WHERE logtime BETWEEN ''2014-10-10 07:17:00'' AND ''2014-10-10 08:47:00'''
```

Also check that `logtime` column is in ranges. You can always print out statemen. After

```
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params, @columns OUTPUT
```

type

```
PRINT @columns
```

and see if that column is included.

Comment: If I want to add a condition that **logtime between ''2014-10-10 07:17:00'' and ''2014-10-10 08:47:00''**, then its showing error that logtime on execution that invlaid column name ligtime.why so..?logtime is the first column name.

Comment: It worked ,Thanks .But can you explain me your sql statement.I did'nt understand it well.What does this @ signifies ??E=What does this **FOR XML PATH('''')),1,1,'''')'** means??

Comment: With `@` you are declaring variables in `MSSQL`. `For XML PATH`, this is a technique to convert many rows to single value. Here it takes all columns of your table and concatenates in string separated with comma.

Comment: That I know, but what this **params NVARCHAR(MAX) = '@columns NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT'** and XML PATH means??

Comment: Here you are providing output parameters for statement in order to capture comma separated columns outside the dynamic query.

Comment: I want distinct values of column 2 to column 20 i.e. irrespective of column 1 .All other values should be distinct.Is it possible with this query using  Row_number() OVER(partition BY )..??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73138/discussion-between-tiddi-rastogi-and-giorgi-nakeuri).

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this to fetch the first 20 columns:

```
select column_name,ordinal_position
  from information_schema.columns
 where table_schema = schemaname
   and table_name = yourtablename
   and ordinal_position <= 20
```

and for fetching the columns from 20th to 60th use this:

```
select column_name,ordinal_position
  from information_schema.columns
 where table_schema = schemaname
   and table_name = yourtablename
   and (ordinal_position > 20 and ordinal_position <= 60)
```

Comment: single quotes will come at schema name and table name.Moreover I want to retrieve values from the column not only there name.

Answer (score 1):

I tried .Thanks Leptonator.

```
SELECT TOP 20 COLUMN_NAME FROM INDUS2_MPS.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'main_mps_dqs_analog'
```

Comment: Oh great. You accepted your own answer which is absolutely incorrect. You wanted also column from 20 to 60 and also VALUES of those column, didn't you?

Comment: yes I wanted, I was clicking at someone else answer but By mistake I did  mine.I corrected it.I didn't accepted any answer as none of them fulfilled my requirement.

Comment: Wasnt this your words `hanks a lot.Its done`? My query is doing exactly what you had asked. You then changed requirement 100 times and I helped you throug chat. It is very bad action fron you. You could ask another question about your further problem or you could continue to chat.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri,sorry, yes I did and I thanked you my problem was solved.I'm currently stuck in a problem,so I forgot. Forgive me.Its my mistake ,i ADMIT. I thanked you on my another post ...the link is-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29094100/using-row-number-overpartition-by-along-with-declaring-local-variables.