# Using Row_number() OVER(partition BY..) along with declaring local variables

Tags: sql-server, inner-join, local-variables, partition-by

I have a sql query, in this sql query I want to select distinct columns irrespective of column first. For other sql query I use Row_number() OVER(partition BY..) and I also need to use inner join. The query in which I want to use row_number and inner join is -

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @params NVARCHAR(MAX) = '@columns NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT'

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT @columns = STUFF(
(
    SELECT '',''+ [column_name] FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE (table_schema = ''dbo''
          AND table_name = ''main_mps_dqs_analog'') 
          AND (ordinal_position <= 73) FOR XML PATH('''')),1,1,'''')'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params, @columns OUTPUT

SET @sql = 'SELECT '+ @columns + ' FROM dbo.main_mps_dqs_analog WHERE logtime BETWEEN ''2014-10-10 07:17:00'' AND ''2014-10-10 08:47:00''' 

EXEC(@sql)
```

I want to apply inner join of this table with `INDUS2_BDS.dbo.ddtable` and I want `beam_current` and `logtime` of this `INDUS2` database table and how to apply partition BY `beam_current` in this query.

Comment: you want to add a inner join and a row_number to your dynamic sql? But you want to PARTITION BY what column? You are not supplying enough information to get actual help... PRINT @sql instead of the execute to see the query you are trying to execute and Google ROW_NUMBER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + @columns + ' ,AnotherTable.beam_current, RowNumber() Over(Partition By SomeColumn Order By SomeColumn) AS Rn
 FROM dbo.TableName join AnotherTable on TableName.SomeColumn = AnotherTable.SomeColumn
WHERE logtime BETWEEN ''2014-10-10 07:17:00'' AND ''2014-10-10 08:47:00'''
```

I solved it by this sql query with the help from  Giorgi